# docker swarm with Centos servers

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I wanted to created a Docker Swarm cluster in which the docker machines are running CentOS or any other OS. How do I do that ?

I see documentation says:

docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

But it creates servers with different OS other than Centos. How do i create a swarm cluster in which each machine is running Centos ?

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Which version of Swarm do you want to use? The classic container base swarm or newer integrated swarm mode? Do the CentOS machines already exist with docker installed?

Comment: I have tried both, docker swarm (old one) and the integrated one with docker-machine.

I installed docker on a Ubuntu box and wanted Centos docker swarm servers.